# How to populate Dictionary object with entries based on certain condition?

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop, enums, conditional-statements

I'm trying to learn C#.I want to create a dictionary whose 1,8,15...167th key should be JUPITER, 2,9,16 .... so on should be MARS etc. Is it possible easier way to make it? Thanks.

```
     public enum Planets : int { JUPITER = 1, MARS, SUN, VENUS, MERCURY, MOON, SATURN }
     Dictionary<int, string> Dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

     for (int key = 1; key < 169; key++)
        {
            if (key % 7 == 1)
            {
                Dict.Add(key, Planet.JUPITER.ToString());
            }
            else if (key % 7 == 2)
            {
                Dict.Add(key, Planet.MARS.ToString());
            }
            else if (key % 7 == 3)
            {
                Dict.Add(key, Planet.SUN.ToString());
            }
            else if (key % 7 == 4)
            {
                Dict.Add(key, Planet.VENUS.ToString());
            }
            else if (key % 7 == 5)
            {
                Dict.Add(key, Planet.MERCURY.ToString());
            }
            else if (key % 7 == 6)
            {
                Dict.Add(key, Planet.MOON.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Dict.Add(key, Planet.SATURN.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: `Planet.MOON` That's no moon. It's a planet.

Comment: :)  It is about :lunarium.co.uk/planets/hours.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about increment by `7` in the `for` and using an offset in the `Add`:

```
 for (int key = 1; key < 169; key += 7)
 {
        Dict.Add(key + 0, Planet.JUPITER.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key + 1, Planet.MARS.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key + 2, Planet.SUN.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key + 3, Planet.VENUS.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key + 4, Planet.MERCURY.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key + 5, Planet.MOON.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key + 6, Planet.SATURN.ToString());
 }
```

or just using `key++` and running until your satisfied:

```
 int key = 1;
 while ( key < 169 )
 {
        Dict.Add(key++, Planet.JUPITER.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key++, Planet.MARS.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key++, Planet.SUN.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key++, Planet.VENUS.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key++, Planet.MERCURY.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key++, Planet.MOON.ToString());
        Dict.Add(key++, Planet.SATURN.ToString());
 }
```

*Revolve in Peace Pluto.*

Comment: Very elegant solution, @HABO!

Comment: I have edited your question for better clarity @PhotonPoint. Good luck with your project (though I am not quite sure if SUN/MOON belongs to this list). Best regards,